# kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to install kafka in ubuntu. I have downloaded the kafka tar.gz file,unzipped it. started the zookeeper server .While trying to start the kafka server, getting the timeout exception.

Can some one pls let me know the resolution.

### Following are the server logs:

```
kafka-server-start.sh ../config/server.properties
[2020-09-17 15:53:02,990] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,310] INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,347] INFO Registered signal handlers for TERM, INT, HUP (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LoggingSignalHandler)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,351] INFO starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,352] INFO Connecting to zookeeper on localhost:2181 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,368] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Initializing a new session to localhost:2181. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,373] INFO Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.5.8-f439ca583e70862c3068a1f2a7d4d068eec33315, built on 05/04/2020 15:53 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,373] INFO Client environment:host.name=LAPTOP-D6RGQ60T.localdomain (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,373] INFO Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_261 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,373] INFO Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,373] INFO Client environment:java.home=/opt/jdk/jre1.8.0_261 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,373] INFO Client environment:java.class.path=/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/activation-1.1.1.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/commons-cli-1.4.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/connect-api-2.6.0.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/connect-basic-auth-extension-2.6.0.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/connect-file-2.6.0.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/connect-json-2.6.0.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/connect-mirror-2.6.0.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/connect-mirror-client-2.6.0.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/connect-runtime-2.6.0.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/connect-transforms-2.6.0.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/hk2-api-2.5.0.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/hk2-locator-2.5.0.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/hk2-utils-2.5.0.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jackson-annotations-2.10.2.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jackson-dataformat-csv-2.10.2.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.10.2.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.10.2.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.10.2.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.10.2.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jackson-module-paranamer-2.10.2.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jackson-module-scala_2.12-2.10.2.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.4.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jakarta.inject-2.5.0.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.5.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/javassist-3.22.0-CR2.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/javassist-3.26.0-GA.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jersey-client-2.28.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jersey-common-2.28.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-2.28.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.28.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jersey-hk2-2.28.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jersey-media-jaxb-2.28.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jersey-server-2.28.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jetty-client-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jetty-continuation-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jetty-http-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jetty-io-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jetty-security-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jetty-server-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jetty-servlet-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jetty-servlets-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jetty-util-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/kafka-log4j-appender-2.6.0.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-2.6.0.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-examples-2.6.0.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-scala_2.12-2.6.0.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-test-utils-2.6.0.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/kafka-tools-2.6.0.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/kafka_2.12-2.6.0-sources.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/kafka_2.12-2.6.0.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/lz4-java-1.7.1.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/maven-artifact-3.6.3.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/netty-buffer-4.1.50.Final.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/netty-codec-4.1.50.Final.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/netty-handler-4.1.50.Final.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/netty-resolver-4.1.50.Final.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.50.Final.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/paranamer-2.8.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/plexus-utils-3.2.1.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/reflections-0.9.12.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/rocksdbjni-5.18.4.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/scala-collection-compat_2.12-2.1.6.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/scala-java8-compat_2.12-0.9.1.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/scala-library-2.12.11.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/scala-logging_2.12-3.9.2.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/scala-reflect-2.12.11.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/snappy-java-1.1.7.3.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/zookeeper-3.5.8.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/zookeeper-jute-3.5.8.jar:/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/../libs/zstd-jni-1.4.4-7.jar (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,374] INFO Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,374] INFO Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,374] INFO Client environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,374] INFO Client environment:os.name=Linux (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,374] INFO Client environment:os.arch=amd64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,374] INFO Client environment:os.version=4.4.0-18362-Microsoft (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,374] INFO Client environment:user.name=sreekanth (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,374] INFO Client environment:user.home=/home/sreekanth (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,374] INFO Client environment:user.dir=/home/sreekanth/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,374] INFO Client environment:os.memory.free=976MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,374] INFO Client environment:os.memory.max=1024MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,374] INFO Client environment:os.memory.total=1024MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,376] INFO Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=18000 watcher=kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$ZooKeeperClientWatcher$@47af7f3d (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,380] INFO jute.maxbuffer value is 4194304 Bytes (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,384] INFO zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled= (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,386] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Waiting until connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,389] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-09-17 15:53:03,392] INFO Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /127.0.0.1:50975, server: localhost/127.0.0.1:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-09-17 15:53:21,394] WARN Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 18001ms for sessionid 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-09-17 15:53:21,394] INFO Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 18001ms for sessionid 0x0, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-09-17 15:53:23,114] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-09-17 15:53:23,115] INFO Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /127.0.0.1:50976, server: localhost/127.0.0.1:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-09-17 15:53:41,117] WARN Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 18001ms for sessionid 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-09-17 15:53:41,117] INFO Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 18001ms for sessionid 0x0, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-09-17 15:53:42,712] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-09-17 15:53:42,713] INFO Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /127.0.0.1:50977, server: localhost/127.0.0.1:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-09-17 15:54:00,714] WARN Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 18001ms for sessionid 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-09-17 15:54:00,715] INFO Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 18001ms for sessionid 0x0, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-09-17 15:54:02,432] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-09-17 15:54:02,433] INFO Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /127.0.0.1:50980, server: localhost/127.0.0.1:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-09-17 15:54:03,388] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closing. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2020-09-17 15:54:20,433] WARN Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 18000ms for sessionid 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-09-17 15:54:20,555] INFO Session: 0x0 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-09-17 15:54:20,556] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-09-17 15:54:20,557] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closed. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2020-09-17 15:54:20,559] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.$anonfun$waitUntilConnected$3(ZooKeeperClient.scala:262)
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:258)
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:119)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1865)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.createZkClient$1(KafkaServer.scala:419)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:444)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:222)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:82)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2020-09-17 15:54:20,561] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2020-09-17 15:54:20,565] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2020-09-17 15:54:20,566] ERROR Exiting Kafka. (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
[2020-09-17 15:54:20,567] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

Comment: Have you tried stopping zookeeper and start zookeeper again to start kafka server..? can you share your kafka termnial cmds with fully qualified path?

Comment: Thank you.I stopped zookeepr and Brokers and started again. It is working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many Zookeeper instances were running earlier. I killed all the zookeeper and Brokers , restarted them again freshly . It is working fine now.

Comment: Can you give me the command? How did you check how many zookeepers are running and how did you kill them?
I tried closing the terminal restarting the laptop but nothing worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I also facing this issue. I have classpath environment variable set up in my Windows 10 for another project. Noticed that when I delete this classpath entry from the environment variables my Kafka able to start perfectly.